# SQL Server 2012 Date datatype contains 12:00:00AM

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC CRUD site that has a Date Approved Textbox. When the new entry is created it is stored properly as "dd-MM-yyyy" in the SQL Sever. When I want to update an entry the Date Required textbox contains the date AND 12:00:00AM . I'm guessing this is because SQL Server is a date datatype and .Net is a DateTime. Any idea how to get rid of the 12:00:00AM ?

Failed attempts...

I've tried adding it to my viewmodel

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name="Date Requested")]
public DateTime?  Date_Requested { get; set; }
```

and also...

```
string test = Convert.ToDateTime(model.Date_Requested).ToString;
```

**EDIT**
the html textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_Requested,new {@class="datepicker" })
```

**EDIT** JQuery DatePicker

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).valid();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you use in the corresponding view to display that textbox? (i.e. the textbox itself and viewmodel definition also)

Comment: I've added the textbox

Comment: Try using `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: I also added the JQuery DatePicker class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add another property, using [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
public string DateRequestedShortDate 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Date_Requested == null ? "" : Date_Requested.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

or simply set the textbox value to the ShortDateString to keep your binding

Comment: I'm receiving the error "cannot convert method group 'toshortdatestring' to non-delegate type 'string'" for the conversion .ToShortDateString() . The code is listed in the question

Comment: `cannot convert method group 'toshortdatestring' to non-delegate type 'string'"` happens when you forget the () parentheses :) It assumes you're trying to pass the method rather than the method's return value.

Comment: Not so much a good call as just a lot of experience with the error ;)

Answer (score 1):

`TextBoxFor` does not honor format attributes (not sure if this is intended or a bug).  You can either use `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Requested,new {@class="datepicker" })
```

or set the format in `TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_Requested,
                          new {
                               @class="datepicker", 
                               @Value = Model.Date_Requested.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") 
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jonesy answer from above.

```
public string DateRequestedShortDate 
{ 
get 
{
    return Date_Requested == null ? "" : Date.Parse(Date_Requested).ToShortDateString();
}
}
```

Parse won't mess up the data being inserted into SQL , hope it helps.

Comment: Side note: If you want to refer to other answers on Stack Overflow, you should avoid using "positional" language such as "above". Due to voting and randomization, the answer "above" or "below" may not be shown as such at a later point in time. Generally, it's better to include a link to the answer you want to refer to.

Comment: I'm not sure why the Parse is necessary here. Could you elaborate?